# Argument-dependent lookup -- when is it done, what is searched, and how can you force (or prevent) it?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm having trouble understanding the rules behind argument-dependent (Koenig) lookup.

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace adl
{
    struct Test { };
    void foo1(Test const &) { cout << "ADL used (foo1)" << endl; }
    void foo2(Test const &) { cout << "ADL used (foo2)" << endl; }
    void foo3(Test const &) { cout << "ADL used (foo3)" << endl; }
}

struct foo1
{
    foo1() { }

    template<class T>
    foo1(T const &) { cout << "ADL not used (foo1)" << endl; }

    template<class T>
    void operator()(T const &) const { cout << "ADL not used (foo3)" << endl; }
};

template<class T> void foo2(T const &)
{ cout << "ADL not used (foo2)" << endl; }

int main()
{
    adl::Test t;
    foo1 foo3;
    (foo1(t));
    (foo2(t));
    (foo3(t));
}
```

Its output is:

> ADL not used (`foo1`)
>   ADL used (`foo2`)
>   ADL not used (`foo3`)

I expected all of them to use ADL, but I was surprised that only some of them did.

What are the (potentially gory, I know) **details** behind the rules of ADL?
I understand the concept well enough, but the details are what I'm having trouble with.

Which scopes are searched, when are they searched, and when are they not searched?

Is it at all possible to tell whether ADL is used without having to look through ***all*** the `#include`'d files before the given line of code? I expected functors and functions to behave the same way in terms of [not] masking ADL, but apparently they don't.

Is there any way to *force* ADL in cases where it is not done automatically (such as the above) and you don't know the class's namespace (e.g. in a template)?

Comment: -1 This question is far too broad, and the code example really sucks (with misleading names etc.).

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you experimenting with `(foo3(t));`? There is no function named `foo3`. So ADL doesn't come into picture. `foo3` will be treated as object, without any doubt, because that is what it is (which means it will call the `operator()` without any doubt)! It is just misleading names you have used in your example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: But there is no confusion over `(foo3(t));`. It is just that he have used misleading names for the variable!

Comment: @Nawaz: Apparently I missed pasting that part of the code, thanks a lot for pointing it out, will fix it. (The output is indeed that ADL is not used when foo3 is included.)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks for all the nice & constructive comments.

Comment: @Mehrdad: you're welcome. hopefully you learned something. next time make an effort with your question, please.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: All your rudeness just because I missed pasting the line for `foo3`? I hope I'm not the only one who finds your "Cheers and hth." ironic, because nothing you've said so far has had anything constructive in it. If you have ideas on how to *improve* the question then I'm all ears, but there's really no need to call me an idiot...

Comment: @Nawaz (and Mehrdad):  Alf is a moron who fancies himself a C++ expert. Based on my own interations with him, I believe he is literally insane. He uses multiple accounts to upvote his own answers (and comments) and to downvote others.  Probably best to ignore him.

Comment: @Nemo: Ouch... I had no idea he has multiple accounts. >_<

Comment: @Nemo: Why should I believe in what *you* believe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't really with argument dependent lookup. First of all, argument dependent lookup only possibly enters the picture when doing unqualified looking up of functions. When calling `foo1(t)` `foo1` is a type and its templated constructor is called. Similarly, `foo3(t)` is a qualified lookup because `foo3` is an object and the function call operator is looked up in the object's class `foo1`. The only place where argument lookup enters the picture is calling `foo2(t)` where lookup finds to candidates:

1. `::foo2<adl::Test>(adl::Test const&)`
2. `::adl::foo2(adl::Test const&)`

These two functions are handed off to overload resolution and since both functions are equally good matches the non-template function wins.

Your question are actually three questions:

1. The gory details of name lookup are too broad and, thus, this question is a request for an essay to be written which I ignore.
2. You second question expands to three more questions, only one seems relevant:

   1. Which scopes are searched? When looking up an unqualified function name inside a function definition the rules depend on whether any of the names is a dependent name. If there is no such name (i.e., in non-template code or in template code where the names can be determined in phase one), the name is looked up enclosing namespaces and in namespaces associated with its argument. Otherwise, the name is only looked up in the associated namespaces.
3. Can argument dependent lookup be forced? It is always done for unqualified function lookups if there is, at least, one argument but names found otherwise may be better matches. Of course, you need to call an unqualified function otherwise it won't be done.

Comment: Still trying to understand what makes a call "unqualified". I thought "unqualified" means "with no qualifier [i.e. namespace] mentioned"... but apparently that's not the case, since none of these mention the namespaces? What does it mean for a call to be unqualified?

Comment: When the names are looked up it first kocates the name and stops when the name is found. `foo1` finds a type and looks up the constructor to call in the context of the type. Since a type was found before a function, no other namespaces are considered. Similarly for `foo3` which is found to be an object for which the function call operator is looked up in the cintext of the object's type. For `foo2` a function is found and the call is unqualified, i.e., namespaces associated with the arguments are searched to augment the overload set.

Comment: That's a good description of the *procedure* that the compiler follows, but I still don't understand what "qualified" means. You seem to be defining qualification as "whatever call that causes ADL", and then saying that ADL is done only for unqualified calls... which is true by definition, but doesn't help me understand what qualifies a call. But what makes a call qualified, exactly? How can I tell whether or not a given call is qualified?

Comment: No, I don't think I do: *unqualified* is when there is no context provided. *Qualified* is when there is a context provided which can be a namespace, a type, or an object (possibly others as well but I can't think of any).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: What do you mean by "context" or "no context"? In this code : `template<typename T> void f(T t) { std::sort;  sort(t.begin(), t.end()); }`. Is `sort` here *qualified* or *unqualified*?

Comment: @Nawaz: By *context* I mean that there is something which restricted where names are being looked up. `sort` in your example is unqualified and probably finds a function. If you preceded the definition of `f()` with something like `typedef T sort;` it would become a constructor call. In the original `(foo1(t))` there is no context when looking up `foo1` which find `foo1` to be a type, followed by a constructor lookup restricted by the context `foo1`. Similarly, `(foo3(t))` finds `foo3` to be an object which becomes the context for the lookup of the function call operator.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: It is still confusing to me. Why `typedef T sort` provides a context but `using std::sort` does not? Also, in C++11, we can even write `using T::sort` instead of the typedef. So it becomes *more* confusing when `using T::sort` provides a context yet `using std::sort` does not. Please explain.

Comment: @Nawaz: When you write `sort` this name is sought without context (unqualified) starting in the local scope, working its way outside. If it finds an entity it stops. If the entity happens to be a function other potential overloads of the function are located and used to build an overload set. If the entity isn't a function lookup of what comes next (e.g. a constructor call for a type or a function call operator for an object or any entity for a namespace) are looked up in the entities context.

Comment: @Nawaz:. That said, I confused the restrictions on using declarations and using directives: A using declarations is matched during lookup, i.e., `sort` in your exampke would refer to the using directive, not the typedef. That is, using `using std::sort;` in the function will resolve to `std::sort`. Sorry for the confusion.