# C++11 `T&&` parameter losing its `&&` correct terminology?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following C++11 code does not compile:

```
struct T {};

void f(T&&) { }

void g(T&& t) { f(t); }

int main()
{
    g(T());
}
```

The correct way to do this is:

```
void g(T&& t) { f(move(t)); }
```

This is very difficult to explain in the correct natural language terminology.  The parameter `t` seems to lose its "&&" status which it needs to have reinstated with the `std::move`.

What do you call the `T()` in `g(T())` ?

What do you call the `T&&` in `g(T&& t)` ?

What do you call the `t` in `g(T&& t)` ?

What do you call the `t` in `f(t)` and `f(move(t))` ?

What do you call the return value of `move(t)`?

What do you call the overall effect?

Which section(s) of the standard deal with this issue?

Comment: `-1` for using misleading name for which I got downvote. You should use other letters instead of `T`.

Comment: @Nawaz: huh, what?

Comment: @jalf: I think he's complaining I used `T` as a struct name and not a template parameter, thus he incorrectly thought `forward` was more appropriate than `move`.

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: maybe, and I agree the name might be ambiguous... but downvoting still feels childish.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I got downvote (probably by OP himself) *precisely* because of `T` which is customarily used for template parameter. If it were `A` , `B` or `X` or anything, that would not happen. Hence, downvote. What makes one to  deviate from the normal, I'm wondering!

Comment: @Navaz: still seems childish and unnecessary to downvote because of it (or because others downvoted you for the same). Wouldn't it be simpler to just say "please delete the first line of your code snippet, so we can pretend `T` is a template type parameter and not the name of a specific type"? Or "please rename `T` to `X`"? Doing something childish to others because it was done to you does not make it any **less** childish. On the contrary.

Comment: @jalf: So when does one downvote if not for misleading name? See [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168890/argument-dependent-lookup-when-is-it-done-what-is-searched-and-how-can-you) where Alf downvoted the question for using misleading name (even though *I realized* (later) the *names* are an integral part of the question!).

Comment: I've actually seen `T&&` parameters referred to as "universal references" since you can pass anything to them, which clears up that `T&&` is not _itself_ an rvalue.

Comment: @MooingDuck: In this example `T` is a concrete struct type, not a template parameter, and as such is not subject to type deduction, and therefore `T&&` in this example is not a ["universal reference"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) as coined by Myers. (You have made a "Nawaz", see previous comments.)

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: Actually, my mistake is different, because I thought it would work even if `T` was a concrete struct.  I appear to have been mistake in that though.  That's weird.

Comment: @Nawaz well, I don't agree with Alf's downvoting policy. I've made that very clear on several occasions. I think it's counterproductive and hostile to other users. In any case, you were pretty much saying "I'm downvoting you because I got downvoted", which is a really lame reason. If you think it's the right thing to do then stick to the actual objective reason. :)

Comment: But since you ask, the mouseover tip on the downvote arrow says to downvote if the question is unclear or not useful, or shows no research effort. Now yes, the `T` is a bit unclear, but I would personally not say it's enough to justify a downvote. But that's just how I see it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point is that a parameter `T&& b` can only bind to an rvalue, but when referred to later the expression `b` is an lvalue.

So the argument to the function must be an rvalue, but inside the function body the parameter is an lvalue because by then you've bound a reference to it and given it a name and it's no longer an unnamed temporary.

An expression has a *type* (e.g. `int`, `string` etc.) and it has a *value category* (e.g. lvalue or rvalue) and these two things are distinct.

A named variable which is declared as `T&& b` has type "rvalue reference to `T`" and can only be bound to an rvalue, but when you later use that reference the expression `b` has value category "lvalue", because it has a name and refers to some object (whatever the reference is bound to, even though that was an rvalue.)  This means to pass `b` to another function which takes an rvalue you can't just say `f(b)` because `b` is an lvalue, so you must convert it (back) to an rvalue, via `std::move(b)`.

Comment: So how do you describe the difference between a parameter `T& a` and a parameter `T&& b`?  Is `a` an lvalue, rvalue, lvalue reference, rvalue reference or several of the above?  Likewise is `b` an lvalue, rvalue, lvalue reference, rvalue reference or several of the above?  If your answer is the same for both questions than in natural language what is the difference between a and b?

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: The key point, I think, is that an *r-value reference* is itself an *l-value*. So, `a` would be an l-value AND a reference and `b` would be an l-value AND a r-value reference (ie, reference to an r-value).

Comment: The _type_ of `a` is "lvalue-reference to `T`", and its _value category_ is "lvalue". The type of `b` is "rvalue-reference to `T`", and its value category is also "lvalue". An expression's value category is a separate thing to its type.

Comment: Ok, so each expression has two distinct characteristics: a type and a value category.

Comment: @MatthieuM. an rvalue reference is not necessarily an lvalue e.g. the expression `std::move(a)` has an rvalue reference type _and_ is an rvalue. (More precisely it's an xvalue, which is a type of of rvalue.)

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps, yes

Comment: @JonathanWakely: yes, you are right, I had only considered named values for some reason :(

Comment: In `3.10 [basic.lval]` Figure 1 is `Expression category taxonomy`, the following page or two explains it I think

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the section that explains it. I've incorporated some of these comments into the answer, thanks both of you for helping me clarify it

Answer (score 7):

All parameters are lvalues, even if their type is "rvalue reference". They have names, so you can refer to them as often as you want. If named rvalue references were rvalues, you would get surprising behavior. We do not want implicit moves from lvalues, that's why you have to explicitly write `std::move`.

Answer (score 5):

> What do you call the T() in g(T()) ?

A temporary (which is movable).

> What do you call the T&& in g(T&& t) ?

T&& is an r-value reference and represent an object that can be moved.

> What do you call the t in g(T&& t) ?

t is actually an l-value since you can refer to it by name.

> What do you call the t in f(t) and f(move(t)) ?

1. l-value
2. l-value being converted into an r-value reference when returned by move()

> What do you call the return value of move(t)?

An r-value reference

As a note; you should maybe call the struct C, and write a separate example where T is actually templetized. The code needs to be different then, because in a function `template< typename T > void f( T&& t );` you cannot simply use `std::move()` without being **very** careful, since T can actually be a `const&`, in which case you **must not** use `std::move()` but instead use *perfect forwarding* with `std::forward< T >( t )`

Comment: To be even more precise, every call of `std::move` is an xvalue.

Answer (score 4):

> What do you call the T() in g(T()) ?

That is a temporary object and an r-value.

> What do you call the T&& in g(T&& t) ?

You call that a r-value reference.

The reason why

```
void g(T&& t) { f(t); }
```

doesn't work is because an r-value reference can't bind to a named object (even if that named object happens to be another r-value reference).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `t` does not lose its "status". Simply, the parameter `t` is an lvalue, even though it is an rvalue reference. Keep in mind that lvalueness and rvalueness are orthogonal concepts and apply to values as to value references (including rvalue references). Thus, an rvalue reference can be either an lvalue or an rvalue. If it has a name, as in your example, it is an lvalue. This makes the type system orthogonal and it is a *good* feature IMHO.

Comment: Do you really mean "lvalueness and rvalueness are orthogonal concepts _to types_"? Otherwise it reads as though you're saying lvalueness is orthogonal to rvalueness, which I don't think is what you mean.  But then I don't understand what you mean by "This makes the type system orthogonal" either so maybe I've just misunderstood the whole answer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yes, I meant to say they are orthogonal to types. What I meant to say is: an object can have type "rvalue reference to something" and still be an lvalue reference (if it has a name), and that the criteria that classify an object as an rvalue or an lvalue are orthogonal to the ones that classify it as an instance of a certain type (e.g. "rvalue reference to something"). I hope i didn't make it just more confusing.